# Make a list of the elements removing numbers and alphabets after numbers

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, logic

```
List=['hello-67.33-yo', 'bye-67-27.34-jk', 'hi56']
g = "".join(List)
S = g.split('-67')[:-1]
```

Expected output

```
['hello','bye', 'hi']
```

This logic works fine for 2 of the elements in the list but I want a solution for all the elements.

Comment: what is the logic for extracting the text why `hello` instead of `helloyo` and what is the expected result in case `56hi56hy`?

Comment: This is the required required result, 56hi56hy is not in the list

Comment: try this regex `^[A-Za-z]+`